# Nested static template member of static template member

Tags: c++, templates, static, static-members

Suppose I have a class which contains static members of a nested template class:

```
class Host 
{
public:

    template<char X>
    class Child {

    };

    static Child<'A'> childA;
};
```

Okay, maybe a little unconventional, but simple enough.  I can define the instance of my static member in a CPP file, thusly:

```
Host::Child<'A'> Host::memberA;
```

Now; suppose the "Child" class *also* contains static members of its own nested template class:

```
class Host 
{
public:

    template<char X>
    class Child 
    {
    public:

        template<int Y>
        class Subchild {
        };

        static Subchild<1> submember01;
    };

    static Child<'A'> memberA;
};
```

How would I go about *defining* the static template member of the static template member?  I've tried:

```
Host::Child<'A'>::Subchild<1> Host::Child<'A'>::submember01;
```

but I get compiler errors:

```
"specializing member "Host::Child<X>::submember01 [with X=(char)'A']" requires "template<>" syntax"
```

This occurs using an ARM compiler, but I do not get this error in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about: (using `template<>` syntax)

```
template<>
Host::Child<'A'>::Subchild<1> Host::Child<'A'>::submember01;
```

Comment: You nailed it.  This turned into a real dumb question.  Extrapolating: if I add another "child" member and "subchild" member, I need to define exponentially more variations using this syntax, right?

Comment: @BTownTKD yes, if I understand what you're trying to define.